# wordpress shortcode formatting issue

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have created a shortcode for my wordpress plugin and shortcode placed between two sentences in the page content of  wordpress. But the two sentences displayed in the bottom of the pugin part .Can may be the issue?

I placed the shortcode as,

My plugin

[PLUGIN]

New wordpress plugin...

But the Html content in the plugin displayed in the top.Then The "My plugin" and "New wordpress plugin..." part in the bottom.I tried a "br" tag between "My plugin" and shortcode.But "My plugin" always displayed under the shortcode part.No bugs found in the HTML code and css.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have used echo in your short code.

Never use echo "Blah Blha" IN your

Ex:

Bad Way

```
function headbox() {
if (is_home()) {
    echo '<div id="headbox">';
    echo '<h1>Test</h1>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_header', 'headbox');
```

Right Way using return

```
function headbox() {
if (is_home()) {
    $foo = '<div id="headbox">';
    $foo .= '<h1>Test</h1>';
    $foo .= '</div>';
        return $foo;
    }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_header', 'headbox');
```